# Can't evaluate field string in type []main.showregister

Tags: go, go-templates

I have a code

```
func profile(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    var tampile = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("./template/profile.html"))
    table := Showprofile()
    var salahe = tampile.ExecuteTemplate(w, "Profile", table)
    if salahe!=nil {
        fmt.Println( salahe.Error() )
        return
    }
}

type showregister struct {
    Namadepan, Namabelakang, Email, Alamat, Kota, Pekerjaan, Jeniskelamin string
    KTP, Nohp, Usia int
}

func Showprofile() []showregister {
    db := GetConnection()
    defer db.Close()

    ctx := context.Background()

    rows, err := db.QueryContext(ctx, "select Nama_depan, Nama_belakang, KTP, Email, Alamat, Kota, No_hp, Usia, Pekerjaan, Jenis_kelamin from register")
    if err != nil {

    }

    dataprofile := showregister{}
    dataprofilee := []showregister{}

    for rows.Next() {
        var namadepan, namabelakang, email, alamat, kota, pekerjaan, jeniskelamin string
        var KTP, nohp, usia int
        err = rows.Scan(&namadepan, &namabelakang, &KTP, &email, &alamat, &kota, &nohp, &usia, &pekerjaan, &jeniskelamin)
        if err != nil {

        }
        dataprofile.Namadepan = namadepan
        dataprofile.Namabelakang = namabelakang
        dataprofile.KTP = KTP
        dataprofile.Email = email
        dataprofile.Alamat = alamat
        dataprofile.Kota = kota
        dataprofile.Nohp = nohp
        dataprofile.Usia = usia
        dataprofile.Pekerjaan = pekerjaan
        dataprofile.Jeniskelamin = jeniskelamin
        dataprofilee = append(dataprofilee, dataprofile)

    }
    defer db.Close()
    fmt.Println(dataprofilee)
    return dataprofilee
}

func dbProfile(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    table := Showprofile()
    for i := range(table) {
        data := table[i]
        fmt.Fprintf(w,"YESS|%12s|%12s|%12s|%20s|%12s|%12s|%12s|%20s%12s|%12s|\n" ,data.Namadepan ,data.Namabelakang , data.KTP , data.Email, data.Alamat, data.Kota, data.Nohp, data.Usia, data.Pekerjaan, data.Jeniskelamin)
    }
}
```

and the html code

```
<div class="col-md-9" style="margin-top: 10px">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value=""> <p class="text-black">{{ .Namadepan }} {{ .Namabelakang }}</p>
                      </div>
```

when i was run the program, the data from database doesn't appear and there was message

> executing "Profile" at <.Namadepan>: can't evaluate field Namadepan in
> type []main.showregister

I just want to show data from database to html using Go as backend.

Comment: It means that `.` in the template, at least at the point where you are trying to access the `Namadepan` field, is of type `[]main.showregister` where `[]` indicates it's a slice type, and slices do NOT have fields, therefore `.Namadepan` is an invalid expression within that context. To fix it you need to either range over `.` in the template, or access it's elements using the `index` template function.

Comment: ... if you go to the documentation of the `text/template` package, you'll find instructions on how to use `range` inside templates and also how to use the `index` template function.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you are passing `[]showregister` - a slice of `showregister` - to the template. In order to access individual struct fields, you will need to range over the slice.

```
{{range .}}
<div class="col-md-9" style="margin-top: 10px">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value=""> <p class="text-black">{{ .Namadepan }} {{ .Namabelakang }}</p>
</div>
{{end}}
```